# How to use @CachePut and @CacheEvict on the same method in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I have a scenario to put `@CachePut` and `@CacheEvict` on the same method.

I tried the scenario with this code given below :

```
@CachePut(value="myValue",key="#entity.getId(),#entity.getOrgId()", 
          cacheManager="no-expire-caching")
@CacheEvict(value="myValue", key="#entity.getId(),#entity.getOrgId()",
          cacheManager="no-expire-caching", condition="#entity.isDeleted() == true")
public MyEntity save(boolean flag, MyEntity entity){
    if (flag==true){
        entity.setIsDeleted(true);
        return myRepo.save(entity);
    }
    return myRepo.save(entity);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as expected.

**Objectives :**

- I want `@CachePut` annotation to always execute first since that will be the first validation to update the cache.
- `@CacheEvict` is executed whenever the condition is satisfied (i.e. `isDeleted` field is set to `true`)
- I don't want my cache to be updated or add a new entry if `isDeleted` is set to `true`.

**Is it possible to achieve this in Spring ? How should I modify my code ?**

Comment: Use condition with CachePut as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the use of multiple different cache annotations on the same method in Spring using `@Caching` annotation.

**Note:** This works when different caches are used.

**According to [Spring Cache Abstraction Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html):**

> When multiple annotations such as `@CacheEvict` or
> `@CachePut` is needed to be specified on the same method for different caches.

> Then to achieve this, the workaround is to use `@Caching`.
> `@Caching` allows multiple nested `@Cacheable`, `@CachePut` and `@CacheEvict`
> to be used on the same method.

Try this (if it works) :

```
@Caching(put={@CachePut(value="myValue",key="#entity.getId(),#entity.getOrgId()", 
          cacheManager="no-expire-caching")}, evict = {@CacheEvict(value="myValue", key="#entity.getId(),#entity.getOrgId()",
          cacheManager="no-expire-caching", condition="#entity.isDeleted() == true")})
public MyEntity save(boolean flag, MyEntity entity){
    if (flag==true){
        entity.setIsDeleted(true);
        return myRepo.save(entity);
    }
    return myRepo.save(entity);
}
```

**[@Caching Java Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Caching.html)** for reference.