# @cachePut for data update in list of object in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

Hi I am using `Spring Boot Cache` in my application. I am able to fetch data from `db` and `cached` that data.

```
 @Cacheable("employee")
public Optional<List<Employee>> employeeData(){
    log.info("Fetched employee details from DB and cached in memory!!");
    return employeeRepository.findActiveEmployee();
}
```

I want to `delete` or `update` or `add new record` in `cached object`.

How can I use `@cachePut` to `update` existing record or `insert` record or `delete` existing record based on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your original method as is to call it whenever you want to fetch data from cache. Note that the `@Cacheable` annotation does not execute the method's body if the cache with name "employee" is not empty, instead it returns the results from cache.

```
@Cacheable("employee")
public Optional<List<Employee>> employeeData(){
}
```

Then proceed in creating a new method annotated with `@CachePut`. Having in mind that `@CachePut` annotation will both **execute** the method as well as **cache** the results **each and every** time:

```
@CachePut(value="employee", condition="#name=='Tom'")
public Optional<List<Employee>> employeeDataCacheByName(String name){
    log.info("Fetched employee details from DB and cached in memory depending on condition!!");
    return employeeRepository.findActiveEmployee();
}
```

The above method will run the query every time and put into `employee` cache the results **if** the `name` argument is "Tom" (condition logic is up to you, this is just an example). This way cache is always updated with the results from the database (as long as the condition is truly evaluated).

For deleting (I don't think `@CachePut` can be used) maybe you can combine the `@CacheEvict` annotation, you can see an example in this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488344/3635454

Comment: Hi pleft, thank you for your response. Is there any other way where I can update the cache on-the-fly? no more db visit.

Comment: @ppb What restricts you only to db? You can write any code you like in the body of the `@CachePut` annotated method and the **returned** result will be cached.